# what is minium api level for android tablets?

Tags: android, operating-system, tablet

I am new android app developer i want make app for tablets and phone . i don't know which api level to create application and  i need sample tutorial to me .please refer tom some books or web link tom me thanks for advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to determine is what is a valid tablet as there are plenty out there running 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.1, 3.1 etc before you even get to the latest ICS which is already on a newer version so this covers levels 7 through to 15.

The other issue is that there are no phones I am aware of running Android 3.X.

I would target level 14 which is ICS but this cuts off many phones running 2.2 and above so you need to code your application to detect what the api level is and run code depending on what the api level is you detect at runtime.

**Additional links courtesy of @Renard**

These libraries seem to offer what you want without you having the headache of dealing with different api levels yourself.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/ and http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: or better yet. Don't worry about api level and use the compatiblity library and projects like [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and [nine_old_android](http://nineoldandroids.com/).

Comment: @Renard thanks for the links I will update my answer